# Umbraco 5 Very Basic - How to load an entity in a macro (or actually using a HiveId)?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5

I've created my first custom Umbraco 5.1 solution. At this point I have a **content item** ("homepage") with a **custom template** which has a **custom partial macro** on it. Now how do I load an entity using the `Umbraco` helper? I've tried adding several `HiveId` constructions using a `Uri`, however I keep getting the same error:

> Parameter 'other' must be of type Guid to convert to a Guid CLR type, but it is 'Uri', with value: xxx

**Macro partial:**

```
@inherits PartialViewMacroPage
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Macros
@using Umbraco.Framework

@{
    //All these fail with the same error message...

    //Based on name:
    var p = Umbraco.GetContentById(
      new HiveId(
        new Uri("content://Homepage")));

    //Based on path
    var p = Umbraco.GetContentById(
      new HiveId(
        new Uri("content://p__nhibernate/v__guid/5a4abe489a2e47858bd2a0580180b683")));

    //With custom Hive provider (I've added this using a custom tree/section and products show up, so the hive provider works)
    var p = Umbraco.GetContentById(
      new HiveId(
        new Uri("custom://products/1")));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why are you creating a Uri?** 
The `HiveId` accepts a string parameter which you can use instead. So does `Umbraco.GetContentById(string id)`

I am Umbraco 5 certified and we never used the `Uri` overload of the `HiveId` constructor.

```
var p = Umbraco.GetContentById("yourStringHiveIdHere"); //(string overload) or 
var p = Umbraco.GetContentById(new HiveId("yourSringHiveIdHere")); // (HiveId overload)
```

Also where are you getting your HiveId from?

Comment: Hmm, ok the first one works, however when I use the `HiveId` overload it doesn't... Also the first one doesn't work for my custom `HiveProvider`. It should just take a "data uri" right?

Comment: @Ropstah I have Umbraco open and just tested both and both worked for me. Is there a reason why you'd use a Data Uri instead of a string/hiveid?

Comment: I must have missed something because they indeed both work... I don't want to go off-topic too much, but what I'd really want is just to query my custom Hive provider using the Helper. I just have no idea on how to get the "Uri" to my entity (i do have a custom tree which show my custom hive provider data in the backoffice)...

Comment: @Ropstah I would imagine that it's something inside your custom hive provider and having to use the URI internally. Why not inspect the Umbraco source on CodePlex? i.e. http://umbraco.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/382fea02040e#Source%2fLibraries%2fUmbraco.Hive%2fConfiguration%2fUriMatchElement.cs

Comment: I thought I could just use the `uri-matches` configuration to make `GetContentById("mycustom://uri/someid")` call `MyProvider.EntityRepository.PerformGet<T>()`. Guess it's not that easy?

Comment: @Ropstah I'm not quite sure TBH. I would post another question regarding custom Hive Providers and probably put it on the Umbraco forums. v5 is still new and am not sure if the devs monitor SO, but they definitely monitor the Umbraco Forums.